# Estimating $1 + H_k$ by $H_{k'}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

The harmonic numbers are $H_k = 1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/k$.

For real $x \geq 1$ let $\kappa(x)$ be the
largest integer $k$ for which $H_k \leq x$. For instance $\kappa(2) = 3$ since $H_3 \leq 2$ and $H_4 > 2$. In a sense $H_{\kappa(x)}$ approximates $x$.

Show that $\kappa(1 + H_k) \sim e k$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? What properties of the harmonic numbers do you know, what are you allowed to use?

Comment: Conjecture based on numerical evidence only. I'm aware of the asymptotic growth of the harmonic numbers.

Comment: The asymptotic growth ($H_n=\ln n+\gamma+O(n^{-1})$) should be enough to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working out Steven Stadnicki's hint, thank you Steven!

For an $n$ where $x \approx H_n$ we have $x \approx \log n + \gamma$, which shows
$\kappa(x) \approx e^{x - \gamma}$. So
\begin{align}
\kappa(1 + H_m) &\approx \exp(1 + H_m - \gamma) \\
&\approx \exp(1 + \log m + \gamma - \gamma) \\
&= e m.
\end{align}
Same sort of argument shows $\kappa(H_m + H_n) \sim e^\gamma mn$ as $m, n \rightarrow \infty$. Nice!

Comment: NB: this is mostly correct but for a proper proof you'd need to provide proper bounds on those $\approx$ sign, specifically using $H_n=\log n+\gamma+O(\frac1n)$.